# How can I reuse a funnel query in Flurry for another app?

Tags: flurry

I've been analyzing an app in Flurry and have created different funnel queries.

Now I have a second app and I want to perform the same analysis, but when I select the new app, non of my funnel queries are available. Making the queries public doesn’t make them visible either…

Is there a way to copy or enable a funnel query from other app?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't currently possible to duplicate or copy a funnel setup- for one app to another app.